# How to get the first and last login of an employee from large data in Codeigniter MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table called Daily_data2 in which i have login and logout details of biometric machine for users. Now a user  may login and go out for some work and come back again login again and may do this many time. So i want fetch only the first Login of a user and last Logout of that user for specific user.

Now i have a table called users which has all the user names and i have mapped the EMP_ID from daily_data2 table so for each user so i can know which user is with which ID.

I have a page called view in which i show the user, his emp_id and either login or logout. Above this i have kept a drop down in which i have passed names from database.

I want select a name from drop down and show only his login/logout details.
Also my code fetches all the login/logout details i just want it to fetch per day first login and last logout.

This is my code:

The View:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                     All Calls Records
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">


                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Emp_ID</th>
                                         <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Entry</th>



                                    </tr>
                                </thead>



                                <tbody>

                                <?php if(count($attendances)): foreach($attendances as $attendance): ?>


                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                       <td><?php echo trim($attendance->emp_id,'">');  ?></td>  
                                        <td><?php echo trim($attendance->name,'">');  ?></td>  
                                       <td><?php echo trim($attendance->date_data,'">');  ?></td>
                                       <td><?php  trim($attendance->entry,'">');  ?>  <?php if($attendance->entry >100)
                                        {
                                            echo "Logged In";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo"Logged Out";
                                        }?>
                                    </td>


                                    </tr>

                                <?php endforeach; ?>

                                <?php else: ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">We could not find any Data.</td>
                                    </tr>

                                <?php endif; ?> 



                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.table-responsive
```

Now a friend recommended this code to get first and last login/logout. But i failed to understand it:

The Model Code:

```
function get_attendance_history($emp_id) {

    $hours = $this->time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 month', time()));
    //desc will print the newest records && asc the latest.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE emp_id = '{$emp_id}' AND date_data > '{$hours}' ORDER BY `date_data` desc /*LIMIT 1*/";

    $result = $this->db->query($sql); //run the query
    //print_r( $result->result_array() ); //debug the result
    //return $result->row()->emp_id; //for one record show..
    return $result->result_array();
    }
```

The Controller Code:

```
  public function login_details() 
       {

        $this->data['attendances'] = $this->attendance_m->don();

        $login_data =$this->data['attends']= $this->attendance_m->get_attendance_history('21');

        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/attendance/view';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
      var_dump($login_data);
    }
```

I want to show something like this:

[image: output]

Comment: whats problem is there? you get any error?

Comment: i cant get the first Login! how wil my code know that this time is first login and xyz-time is the last logout of any employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this
SELECT * from( 
   SELECT * from (SELECT daily_data2.*,max(date_data) FROM daily_data2 WHERE emp_id = '{$emp_id}'  AND date_data between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31' group by emp_id order by date_data desc ) as A
    Union
    SELECT * from (SELECT daily_data2.*,min(date_data) FROM daily_data2 WHERE emp_id = '{$emp_id}'  AND date_data between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31' group by emp_id order by date_data desc ) as B

) as order by emp_id

start_month date = 2015-01-01
end_month_date = 2015-01-31

Comment: thanks for your answer but could not understand will you please eleborate